# Improve question quality by informing users of reverse image search sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, identification-questions, asking-questions

Over at [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com), a lot of users come with images of anime fan art, cosplays, gifs, etc and ask who the character is, or which show they are from.

The only problem with these questions is that we get a lot of badly researched questions. Specifically, users could put their images into [Google Image Search](http://www.google.ie/imghp) or similar reverse image search engines and get their answer quickly.

For example, [this id request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/help-me-find-this-anime-with-a-red-haired-character-who-has-a-tattoo-on-their-fo) can be easily discovered with a quick search

What I propose is that when a low-rep user is writing one of these questions (tagged "identification-request" & containing an image), a message advising users of these identification methods could be shown.

[image: warning]

We have a [meta question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-can-i-identify-an-anime-using-reverse-image-search) on our site about how users can go about finding image sources themselves.

I believe this measure could help question quality significantly.

Comment: This would also be useful on TV&Movies and Sci-Fi sites, because they also have identification questions.

Comment: Arqade could benefit from it too - game identification is off-topic without an audiovisual artifact, but often those questions boil down to a google reverse image search of that same artifact.

Answer (score 21):

We *could* add this to the sidebar help on /questions/ask, but first let's try something a bit more direct:

[image: Are you looking to identify the subject of an image? Try using Reverse Image Search first!]

This will appear any time someone uses the [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) tag. It won't stop them from posting the question, but it *should* catch their attention - and it provides a direct link to [the relevant post](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618).

Comment: I like this approach more

Comment: Ooooooh, fancy!

Comment: No. If you need the text changed, just let me know what it should be @Prix.