# Should we migrate SciFi-related identification request to SciFi.SE?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions, migration

Some people on SciFi.SE seem willing to accept identification request [and is asking on their meta if the community wants](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11552/23127).

As for now, we don't have the option to properly migrate them. Should we migrate science fiction and fantasy related identification requests to SciFi.SE?

Comment: As things stand we have a +11 on [the proposal on Meta:SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11553/20774). In short, yes, we definitely want them!

Comment: For example, this one; https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43492/i-want-to-know-the-name-of-the-anime-that

Comment: For example, this one; https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43505/help-me-find-this-bleach-fanfiction

Comment: This one wouldn't be on-topic as it has no obvious fantasy content; https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43542/an-old-anime-about-sea-animals

Comment: Another great candidate here; https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43578/how-can-i-find-an-anime

Comment: This one is borderline, but based on the fact that she's dressed in a fantasy outfit, I'd err on the side of it being passed over; https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43582/what-is-the-name-of-the-manga

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If SF&F wants these questions (god knows why they would), I am happy to kick any new ones we get that are sufficiently science-fictional or fantastical over to them.

I do not support opening a formal migration path (i.e. making SF&F a migration target available to non-moderator close-voters) at this time. For the time being, it would be better for migration candidates to be identified in the following ways:

- users see potential migration candidates and cast custom flags indicating they should be migrated to SF&F
- I and other moderators directly migrate candidates to SF&F if we catch them before they are deleted
- I (and possibly other moderators) look through our closed/deleted questions every so often (maybe a couple times a week) for candidates that got wiped out before we had a chance to look at them, and evaluate them for undeletion + migration as appropriate

If this works, we can then work on opening a formal migration path and encouraging non-moderator close-voters to directly migrate without need for moderator intervention.

---

I do have some concerns about this. Chief among them is SF&F's requirement that the identification request "Appears to contain a uniquely identifiable question". This is a nebulous and ill-defined requirement. We have had various debates about similar requirements on *this* site (back before we'd banned id-reqs altogether), and my stance has always been that one simply cannot know (in the vast majority of cases) whether the text of an id-req uniquely identifies a single work. I will make a good-faith attempt to guess whether a question uniquely identifies a single work (or whether such information could be coaxed out of the asker with nominal effort), but it is entirely possible that my sense will not align with SF&F's voters' senses and we will get a lot of rejected migrations as a result.

Also, to be blunt, our id-reqs have historically been substantially lower-quality than SF&F's and you're probably not going to like them once they start appearing on your site. Doubly so, given that the id-reqs we get *these days* are exclusively from people who have no presence on this site and have not read any of the site rules, and hence are probably not inclined towards putting substantial effort into their questions.

---

But anyway, tl;dr: my take is that users should cast custom flags for migration, and we'll look at them. (Not starting immediately, though; we should wait a bit for our two metas to settle into a consensus. We moderators are also discussing this matter amongst ourselves [as, at least initially, it would be us upon whom the burden of this migration stuff would fall].)

Comment: "Uniquely identifiable" simply means that the user hasn't simply identified a [common trope](http://tvtropes.org/) as being the thing that's memorable.

Comment: Note that questions that would get insta-deleted here seem to be pretty well received on SFF; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175064/what-anime-is-the-clip-mentioned-below-from

Comment: Echoing Richard, it doesn't actually have to be uniquely identifiable.  It just has to not consist entirely of the sentence *I saw this anime with a girl who had a funky transformation sequence who is she?*  As long as it broadly looks like the person is describing a particular story, we're entirely content to just leave it open and unanswered indefinitely or until they provide more detail.  We already have [a ton of unanswered story ID questions anyway](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11413/36526).

Comment: been two months and it's currently what we do I decide to accept this answer

Answer (score 10):

I do not think we we should. I see no benefit at all in a migration path. It just puts more effort on the moderation staff to handle all the things, as regardless of infrequently as these questions occur. As many have mentioned in the comments, it puts lot of unnecessary burden on the moderation staff.

If people are adamant about this happening, I'd suggest for certain conditions for migration. If SFF.SE wants our identification-type questions that fit their criteria, they will need to establish a set of clearly definable criteria and actively request questions for migration on a case by case basis. It is not the responsibility if the moderation staff to actively monitor and migrate these questions.

If users from the other communities would like our off-topic questions, they should make an attempt to participate in our community for them. If we wanted something similar from their community, I would ask for the same amount of participation from our users.

The moderators have dealt with these questions for almost 3 years and a quite weary of them. We're familiar with how a vast majority of the question are not very comprehensible or sometimes even relevant to anime.

We allow questions on the topic of hentai, as long as it does not involve explicit material or details (yes, it gets tricky to draw the line, but we manage), as it violates the content policy. Without a set criteria it's hard to say what works and what doesn't. Different communities do things differently after all. How some users define "fantasy" is questionably subjective in my opinion. Talking animals doing human like thing can be considered "fantasy-like", while something setting like *Charlotte's Web* might not. Ambiguity and subjectivity will just more difficult for everyone in the long run.

The Stack Exchange community works the way it does thanks to it's community and users. If there is a set criteria to match questions appropriate for migration, I don't see the problem with it, if community pitches in to help.

Additionally, there is no merit in the migration of historically locked questions. The whole reason they are locked and not completely deleted is to reminded users of the deprecated nature of these question.

Comment: I fully agree re: historically-locked questions. Those certainly shouldn't go anywhere. As for this needing to be a community-driven effort rather than a moderation-driven effort - I agree that in the long-run, moderator-based curation of migratable questions is not sustainable, but I think it's reasonable to try that as a "pilot" of sorts. (Which is not to say that _you_ should have to spend any time doing that, but I think it is worthwhile, so I would if we end up agreeing that this is something worth trying.)

Comment: This has been discussed before. In short, We've decided that a work merely having talking animals *in it* isn't defined as fantasy unless their presence is somehow fantastical; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy. That being said, I'm struggling to think of any anime/manga where the characters are personified animals.

Comment: I've been keeping an eye on the queues for the past couple of weeks. The volume of relevant migrations is probably about 3-4 per week, hardly something that qualifies as a substantial volume of extra work, especially when split between 3 mods.

Comment: You don't see any benefits over migrating them somewhere they're welcome over deleting them with a terse message about not being welcome here?

Comment: I don't either. What benefits do you propose?

Comment: I try put the interest of the moderation staff and this community before anything else when it comes to new policies. You seem to prescribe that your community is doing us a favor by taking these unwanted questions off our hands, however our mods will likely be left with the brunt of the labor. The infrequency of these questions, as to pass it off a minor triviality. The main issue I see with this request is that your community comes in and ask us to migrate questions, but offer to contribute little to nothing in return. If this was an equivalent exchange, I wouldn't have any particulars.

Comment: @Unihedron - Well, treating new users with respect, even if their first question is a bit naff.

Comment: @кяαzєя - The return is happy, engaged users (anime fans, to boot) who'll stick around in the network and may see other questions they'd like to ask/answer. As it stands you're simply pushing them away and telling them how unwelcome they are, period.

Comment: Anime fans aren't the type to be engaged, they are primarily motivated by their own self interest and unmotivated by sloth most of the time. We've had some pretty bad ones in the past, like one individual working for or volunteering at museum in the Southern US asking us to identify possibly hundreds of anime cels, but got stopped my the question post limit. We dealt with and tried to reason with them many times in many ways, with very low returns. It's a matter of give and take here you will get as much out of it as you put in. We'll gladly work with you if you put in the time and effort.

Comment: @кяαzєя: I see where you're coming from, but this "equivalent exchange" would be a lot easier on us if y'all didn't aggressively delete these questions before anyone could look at them... most of us don't have the rep to view deleted.  It's a bit unrealistic to expect us to comb Google's cache for these things.  Frankly, I also think you were so quick to quote Fullmetal Alchemist that you forgot its moral: *Life doesn't have to be a zero-sum game.*

Comment: Humankind cannot gain something without first giving something in return. To obtain, something of equal value must be lost. Unlike SFF.SE, the rep required to see deleted questions is still at pre-graduation thresholds, 2k, and not likely to change any time soon. If you want these questions all you need to do is participate in the community. It doesn't take that much effort.

Answer (score 8):

Just gonna leave a couple of thoughts here.

First, it doesn't seem reasonable to me for this community and its mods to have to take the burden of quality controlling these questions for another community, since they've been considered off-topic here. If SF&F found a way to make it work for them, awesome — but it shouldn't be expected for this community to go around and make sure questions check all the boxes in SF&F's quality guidelines for these types of questions.

It would also be unreasonable, however, to just migrate everything wholesale there, since most of the id-req stuff that gets posted here is low-quality (one of the reasons we ended up doing away with 'em).

Both of those reasons seem like pretty good reasons not to enable the migration path, to me.

Now, that being said, I do know that there's some overlap between users of both communities... so if anyone who is really active at SF&F and familiar with their guidelines sees something here they definitely think is a good fit there, great! **Leave a comment** suggesting the asker re-post their question on SF&F (and delete the one they posted here).

[As Hakase mentions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4134/49), you can always follow our bot in the main chat room, and drop some guidance when something interesting that'd be a good fit on SF&F is found.

This way, the question isn't orphaned: if the asker cares enough to join a new site and re-ask it, they probably also care enough to stick around and respond to clarifications, add necessary details, *accept a correct answer if one arises...*

And if they're *already* gone, no additional work is needed - we can just neatly leave it in our curb until the garbage man comes by... that is, [the community deletes it](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2824/49).

[Richard mentions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4133/should-we-migrate-scifi-related-identification-request-to-scifi-se?cb=1#comment8368_4134) we delete these new questions too quickly for anyone to react, though. Well... that's great, to be honest! Because it means we clean up our front page real quick :) But, to the point of this discussion: the close reason can always be *slightly* edited, so it gently points these users to SF&F — I don't *think* it'd make everyone who asks these questions here go there, but some of the most attentive ones might... and hopefully that's the subset of people who ask better quality id-reqs? IT could, however, have the exact same result as dumping all of these questions on SF&F, so I'm not so sure it'd be a great idea.

Comment: Relying on users from another site to flag is not feasible. I've been checking in 5 times a day and I'm still missing about 50% of them. Luckily most get cached but expecting a custom flag is just unreasonable. The entire point of the migration pathway is to give users an *alternative* to simple deletion.

Comment: @Richard: "to give users an alternative to simple deletion." - This is not a good alternative when it means having to commit to decide that it will work for a different community, and it shouldn't be our reviewers' problem to figure out which option is better. It needs to be straightforward otherwise it is a big toll for effort.

Comment: @Unihedron - I fail to see why everyone think's it's so amazingly hard to apply two simple tests; A) is it fantasy/scifi? B) Does it look uniquely answerable? If that's the case then that means it's **off-topic here but on-topic elsewhere**, which is the entire reason that migration exists.

Comment: @Richard "Does it look uniquely answerable?" - If it is an identification request, no.

Comment: @Richard Sorry, I think you're missing the point here. It will be a lot of work for us because we're not you. We don't know what constitutes an answerable post in terms of Sci-Fi and we've already established that ID-reqs tend to be crap. **Both *"Help. I'm trying to remember a story about a giant robot"* and *"Help. What is this story about a giant robot called an Eva"* are the same to us and now we're expected to guess that Sci-Fi will accept the second question despite both being as low quality.**

Comment: @Unihedron - In my experience most are. You do occasionally get a stinker but they're pretty rare. It's not hard to work out which are irrationally vague and which aren't

Comment: @Unihedron - And again we're talking about one or so candidates every two days. Not big volumes.

Comment: @Richard Adding a migration option would also mean **every new identification request** with more than a line needs to be scanned for fantasy. Having to cast judgement **while not having an unambiguous criteria** makes it even more of a chore. This was supposed to be an alternative to simple deletion, so it needs to be easy to use. "Uniquely answerable" is not specific - **voting "does it belongs on superuser.com" from SO is not work at all, answering "does it look uniquely answerable" to a question that is inherently incomplete (which is why identification is requested) is not.**

Comment: @Unihedron - It strikes me that there's a real streak of "*these people should be punished because they're asking questions that we've decided are off-topic"* in the answers that I'm seeing rather than "*We should make some effort to help these users even though they've asked a question that's off-topic"*.

Comment: @Richard It doesn't strike me and I encourage you to do research on why they are deemed off-topic and banned in the first place. This discussion is both going off-topic and unconstructive in regards to addressing the actual answer in question so I'm going to drop it. You're welcome to have an extended discussion in chat or add points to your existing (or a new) answer.

Comment: I feel like you're missing the point, @Richard: this community spent a _huge_ amount of time trying to curate these types of question, and keeping them in our site. We had a set of criteria. We went through the trouble of asking the users to include more details. And then we finally decided to stop doing that, because it was too much trouble for the benefit of a very little amount of users — users that weren't even gonna contribute to the community either. After all that, it is not reasonable to ask _this community_ to check if question comply to a set of guidelines _set by another community_.

Comment: (cont.) Especially, as I stated before, after we had our own, and decided to get rid of 'em. It just feels like you're asking this community to do a job they stated pretty clearly they didn't wanna do any more. I'd advise you read [this post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2805/49) and all the other ones linked to from it — it provides a really thorough overview of the community's fight against these, and why it seems so unreasonable of you to ask us to do this.

Comment: @JNat - I recognise how much time you spent getting to this point. The question is how to most effectively engage with these users *from this point onward* in a constructive way. Simply deleting their questions and making them feel unwelcome doesn't feel constructive, especially when another site within the Stack is willing and able to take their questions enthusiastically.

Comment: That's all cool, but now we get to that bit of the discussion that just throws us into a circle: you can't expect _this community_ to check for whether or not guidelines _set by another community_ are being met. Unless there's something in this discussion that throws us out of this loop, Imma drop it here ;)

Comment: I'd be happy with modifying the close reason, though I think it's kind of confusing when the close reason *only mentions SFF.SE if it has SciFi element* (kind of discriminating, eh?). Instead, I'd really like to reconsider this: [Let's change the ID request close reason plaque to redirect askers to other sites](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4123/2516)

Answer (score 5):

### No

The proposal is reasonable on paper but **unrealistic** in terms of grounds for execution.

The benefits are too small for Anime.SE - which already banned this type of questions after having dealt with them for long enough to identify it as **problematic** - to be worth the effort.

The questions in concern are **not dire** for migration - If a question is closed but meets the standards for Sci-Fi, the question askers can already be manually redirected as-is.

Handling identification requests to decide if they're worth migrating shouldn't be the problem of that of our moderators and/or reviewers. However, the linked discussion thread on Sci-Fi.Meta.SE includes the following points:

> Anime's own users and mods will do some quality control for us, ensuring that inappropriate questions (such as those that don't contain any SFF content) won't get migrated over.

> We've had a TON of migration discussions on SO, and they inevitably break down because the target site gets a lot of rejected migrations. Invariably, what will happen is it will promote the lowest common denominator. "Oh, a story ID question. Off to SFF you go!", only to have us now do more work to close the ones not in the rules.

> if ID questions are getting closed over there that would be upvoted and answered over here, then there's no reason not to deprive those questions' OPs of getting their answers.

These quotes outline the two main problems behind the migration option:

1. It is an **idealistic implementation** with the hopes that our users can identify questions that are worth Sci-Fi.SE's users' time. However the last major thing we have been able to decide is that **they aren't worth our own time** (even after trying to improve and fix them), so our users are not likely to re-learn **a new set of quality guidelines** for identification questions that we've already tried before and has in no way worked out, not barely.
2. This generates **unnecessary work** as a side effect. Where as currently "identification questions are off-topic, because they tend to attract low-quality and low-effort posts", the proposal has not addressed the problems (why do you want floods of low-quality and/or low-effort posts?) (edit: have not appeared to discuss in regards to remedying the problems to be worth the effort) and wants our questions that are fantasy-related. This leads to every new identification request having to be scanned for fantasy, it's not a trivial amount of work for a pool of questions that Sci-Fi users have no promise to fix into shape.

---

Conclusion: Implementing the migration path appears to be a liability, and as there is no compromise to be made, it doesn't seem like a good solution. However, as with all solutions, they should be implemented to solve a problem. While a migration path is not a good solution, there may exist others when the problem is identified.

Identification questions has made up a large percentage of our regular "income" before they were banned, so there is definitely a "market" there but there needs to be more realistic ways to get questions over to Sci-Fi (while taking into account that we want all of them out of here without worrying about fine grains).

I can't imagine that Sci-Fi isn't already getting its fair share of animated fantasy works and the existing field there is healthy. Implementing this migration path without solid promise for their users to be doing the work to fix them into shape would only pollute this small haven and waste both of our communities' time.

---

Addendum: Recently, some users <sub>(should this even be plural? I didn't notice if they were the same persons)</sub> have been manually redirecting question askers for the possibility of reposting their question there. [You can judge the results for yourself.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification+anime?sort=newest)

---

Post script: I didn't realize what a migration path meant, I assumed the discussion was surrounding opening a new close vote option for all reviewers. While I think that good questions that could find a home on Sci-Fi.SE safely may be worth migrating to on a case to case basis, it shouldn't be Anime.SE's job to identify them.
Post-post script: I was right in assuming what a migration path meant, ignore this block. As things are now, manual migration by moderators is already possible.

Answer (score 4):

I think a lot of our users here want nothing to do with ID requests anymore, and we wouldn't mind if they (SciFi users) filtered through them and took what they like. (comment if you disagree)

Migration requires 5 votes (if I'm not mistaken), but I don't think anyone here wants to think about whether it's a worthy question to migrate. Because there is a "don't migrate crap" policy and SciFi has their own set of rules for ID request quality, this is kind of a headache.

If the SciFi users really want this to happen, they'll have to follow all of our newly posted questions. In chat, [Sakamoto](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-179/sakamoto?tab=recent) does this for our room, and they could also subscribe to the same feed in their chat room to monitor new questions. Then SciFi users would have to come and vote to migrate if they deem it useful.

So this is a way to enable this without requiring any extra action from our users or moderators.

Comment: The problem with this is that y'all are so quick at deleting them that we mere mortals can't even see them.

Comment: The other issue is that our chatroom recently got closed down. A new one has opened but it only receives a small handful of messages a day. Placing a feed to *all* Anime questions would swamp the few user messages it gets each day.

Comment: I'll be going through the trash pile in the next few days to see if I can pick out some of those under 60 days old to get the ball rolling.

Comment: how are you gonna do that? you don't have enough rep here to see deleted posts

Comment: I was going to use google cache

Comment: you may try to get an idea of the post from Sakamoto's oneboxes if that's any help

Comment: not sure if it's possible to migrate closed question but we can start with not del voting them that way if there are some user who want to read it can flag them. Now it depend if our mod willing to see and migrate these question or not

Answer (score 2):

Y'know, I'm late to the conversation and I'm late to how this has panned out, but from my perspective we've been doing this for at least most of December.

My take on this:

## I *hate* it.

I hate the idea of giving another community the detritus that we genuinely didn't want.  It makes me think that we're giving them hand-me-downs that have been utterly ruined in ways both imaginable and unimaginable.

I hate the idea of catering to a demographic of user who is only here for an *instant*, who only want to engage based on this one premise, and will not add positively to any community.  I get that I'm painting a group of people with a broad brush, but [there is some data to back me up on this.](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/do-identification-request-questions-attract-users-that-dont-contribute-to-the-s)

I hate even thinking that these questions are suitable for Stack Exchange's Q&A style ***period***, given that they're really...not.  This gets to the heart of asking what the purpose really *is* for SciFi.SE.

I hate the idea of migrating what essentially is grunt work; even if the other side of the fence is willing to accept it, it feels like a non-trivial amount of effort for a trivial gain.

---

I feel like identification questions have no real value anywhere that they go.  I genuinely fear that SciFi may run into the same fork in the road that we did three or so years ago with them.  Learn from our lesson; **don't accept any more.**  It's not going to make your community any better.  It's not going to make *ours* any better for sending them over since it won't change the fact that we get them at all.  For those who think that this'll lead to users shifting their attention to SciFi instead...given how often they contribute to the site *after* they ask an identification question, I have *strong* doubts.

---

To go a bit more into providing some data, (at the time of writing) I have access to the stats for migrated questions.

In the last 90 days (from 2 January 2018):

- 10 questions have been migrated to SciFi.SE

Of those 10 questions:

- All of them score above zero

  - 2 score above 10
- ***None*** of the OPs have registered accounts on the site after migration (a problem for a site trying to become full-fledged, may be less of a problem for already full-fledged sites)
- 6 have at least one answer

  - 2 have more than one answer

To put that into perspective with Area 51's applicable metrics, which are:

- An average of 2.5 answers per question
- 90% of questions answered

The migrated questions have:

- An average of **0.9 answers per question**
- **60% of questions answered**

I entirely recognize that this is early days and that these are a small sample set.  However, I'm not convinced that just accepting these questions from us is going to be the best approach here, nor do I feel like it's going to improve either community in the long run.

Comment: We like them. We like them a lot. We like answering them and making new users happy and we have a hard core of users who positively thrive on these questions. More = Better, especially in the small additional volumes that Anime:SE could potentially provide

Comment: Also, treating this "*demographic of user*" as second-class citizens isn't an  especially nice attitude.

Comment: @Richard:  Thanks for for your feedback.  However, the numbers aren't misleading there; the users who do ask these kinds of questions tended not to stick around here.  It's tough for me to get excited or motivated to help those sorts of users if they're not going to positively help a community build or grow.  Given that A&M is still relatively infant and hasn't fully graduated yet, I feel like we do want to emphasize lasting user contributions, content and users who want to help out with making this site succeed.

Comment: @Richard:  Honestly - and I am just being honest - I don't feel like they're the sort of user we should be optimizing for.  I get it if SciFi wants to, but I don't feel like we should be sending them over the fence.

Comment: We want them sent over the fence, thank you.

Comment: @Richard:  I'm really not trying to be argumentative, but I'm not seeing a compelling reason here *to* send them over besides, "Yes, we'll take them."  I'm not seeing any information as to how you've prevented the situation from spiraling out of control, nor have I seen any evidence from SciFi's perspective that users that *do* ask those sorts of questions actually stick around.  If I could have maybe one or two of those concerns allayed, I'll happily withdraw my point.

Comment: Well, entirely ignoring the fact that one of your moderators started by asking a low-quality ident question, we've now had at least three of the users who've had their questions manually migrated join the site proper and one of those has asked a further (Harry Potter) question. I'd call that a win, although what I thought would be a trivial ask (can we, sure you can) has turned into something a lot more involved.

Comment: @Richard:  I did say that I didn't want to *optimize* those sorts of users, not outright ignore them.  We've *genuinely* been spurned by them in the past, and I get that not all of them were bad; some of them turned out to be fantastic.  However, I don't see the data to suggest that these sorts of questions have contributed positively to SciFi.SE, nor do I feel particularly assured by "Yes, we'll take them on" as the only real reason to send them over.

Comment: Well, the questions that have been sent over have received substantial numbers of upvotes (indicating community approval) and where answered, they've had a similar number of upvotes and very few downvotes.

Comment: @Richard:  I've added some more stats into this.  I think I fully understand SciFi's position on this, but I don't feel that my concerns have been allayed any less from it.

Comment: I think the metric are a bit misleading. These are story ID questions. Having ***multiple competing answers*** suggests a failure rather than a success.

Answer (score -5):

**Yes, absolutely we should take them up on their offer.** Having to close and delete ID questions is a hassle, but that doesn't mean that we can't still take a few extra seconds to point those users to somewhere they might find help.

As has been pointed out, waiting for a five user quorum (for a formal migration) is probably the wrong way to go with this. Since these questions are *definitely going to be deleted* (and hence there will be little controversy over them being migrated instead of deleted), it's far simpler to have the moderators use their powers to move them over as soon as they're seen **by raising a custom moderator flag on them.**

> **"*Hey moderator, this would be a good fit for SFF and should be migrated*"**

---

### What can we flag to migrate?

Anything that meets the following three simple-to-understand conditions;

- **Contains science fiction or fantasy content**
- **Not Hentai / Animated pornography**
- **Appears to contain a uniquely identifiable question** (so "*Help. I'm trying to remember a story about a giant robot*" would be a no but "*Help. What is this story about a giant robot called an Eva*" would be a yes)

If there are any problems, the migration will simply get rejected but as long as you've followed the three rules above, the chances of that happening are next to zero.

Comment: one little problem: our mods might not be in the mood to figure it all out, and it might end up either being "everything migrated" or "nothing migrated". If it's possible for the SciFi mods (who are not mods on A&M) to do this, then sure, no issues. I mean we collectively decided to stop thinking about IDs here because it brings everybody's mood down, including our moderators. So… I guess we can wait to hear what they think about this now. Currently there are 2 active mods here.

Comment: @Hakase - It's not a high volume exercise. I'm sure your mods can handle an extra couple of custom flags a week :-)

Comment: There were at least three identification questions posted today, so it's potentially a lot more flags than that. Your suggestion essentially comes down putting the burden on the moderators here to decide whether the crap that gets posted here wouldn't be considered crap on the Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange site. Also note the standard for moderation approval of migrations is supposed to be high. It should only happen for great questions that the moderator is sure is on-topic on the destination site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247250/how-important-is-migration

Comment: @RossRidge - Looking at the Sakamoto feed in chat, it would appear that only one of those ID questions contained any "*science fiction or fantasy content"*. The other two were a hentai(?) about a pervert and some kind of slice-of-life set in a school. The latter two would have been rejected, the first would have been accepted.

Comment: @RossRidge - [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration) is a much better target if you're interested in the Meta:SE thinking behind migrations; "*If the question is off-topic or unanswered and the flagger has a good bit of reputation on the target site, go ahead and migrate. - If the question is off-topic but seems reasonably well-written and you understand it well enough to believe it belongs on the target site, migrate.* - Both aspects apply. These questions are off-topic on Anime and firmly on topic on SFF

Comment: Just one note: for what it's worth, mods rarely just migrate stuff to other sites willy-nilly (at least from my experience). Instead, the most common way mods go about migration is by asking mods from the other sites on a per-question basis, in the Teacher's Lounge.

Comment: @JNat - Indeed, but given the volume (approx 3-4 per week at present rates) and the fact that Anime:SE is blanket deleting these questions, I thought a more formal arrangement would be more worthwhile.

Comment: I'm sure the point has been discussed in earlier threads, but blanket closing of these ID requests is the opposite of newbie-friendly.  Sure, some of the posters are one-time only posters anyway.  But some have the potential to become active in the community if they don't feel completely shut down on their first post.

Comment: I'm actually puzzled by the amount of resistance this proposal is getting, but I don't participate here much anymore so I haven't said much. One thing I do want to point out: when we did id requests here we had a lot of requests for porn that no one (including the user asking the question) knew were for porn until someone had answered the question. Supposing the tide turned and people supported this idea (I know senshin has been tossing some over to you guys), how okay are you guys with getting the occasional accidental porn request?

Comment: @Torisuda - We have a reasonable tolerance for adult content as long as there's no explicit pictures or messy descriptions.

Comment: @Richard Thanks, good to know. A related problem could be if someone who doesn't want to look at tentacle porn unwittingly goes Googling for an answer to one of these questions and gets an eyeful of something horrific. Not much to do about that, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: @Torisuda - If you've gotta go hunting for it, you're probably old enough to be tolerant of it :-)